# Why am I getting "The type parameter must be invariantly valid..." error?

Tags: c#, generics, factory-pattern, variant

I'll attempt to shorten this code example:

```
public interface IThing
{
    //...  Stuff
}

public class Thing1 : IThing
{  
}

public class Thing2 : IThing
{  
}

public interface IThingView<out T>
{
    ICollection<T> ViewAll();
}

public class ThingView<T> : IThingView<T>
{
    ICollection<T> ViewAll() { return new List<T>(); }  //  There's a big operation here
}

public interface IThingViewerFactory
{
    public IThingView<IThing> Build(string Which);
}

public class ThingViewerFactory
{
    public IThingView<IThing> Build(string Which)
    {
        if(Which.Equals("Thing1") { return new (IThingView<IThing>)new ThingViewer<Thing1>();}
        else { return new (IThingView<IThing>)new ThingViewer<Thing2>();}
    }
}
```

That's a rough idea of what I'm doing.  I have a number of Thing classes that require a viewer, which will follow a comon interface.  I'd like a factory to generate these by me passing in a string with the name.  I keep getting a compiler error complaining:

Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IThingView.ViewAll()'. 'T' is covariant.

I realize even if I get this to work, I'll have to do some casting afterwards... I'm fine with that.  And I realize this approach is more than likely not necessary.  At this point this has become more of a pride/curiosity issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note: `Which.Equals("Thing1")` will leave you vulnerable to `NullReferenceException` which is simply unprofessional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot make a covariant `ICollection<T>`, since it allows you to put `T`s into it.

You can make a covariant read-only collection, a contravariant write-only collection, or an invariant read-write collection.
You can't do both, or it wouldn't be typesafe.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on SLaks answer:
To make your code compile, change the return type of `ViewAll` from `ICollection<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.