# Unity GetComponent Generic type

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, covariance

While helping a friend today, I came across a problem in Unity. The GetComponent method is generic, and needs a Type, until so far, nothing wrong.

I am using a Finite State Machine (FSM) match states to certain entities. For that case, I use generics. Every Entity, inherits from StateMachine, for this cause.

Now, when I loop through all entities in the scene, I want to get their Entity script and get a variable from it, in this case: IsKillable.

But, when Unity asks for a type, I want to give it the type: "Entity", but not "Entity" or "Minion" because I need to duplicate the functionality for every type I have.

Trying to solve that, I removed the inheritance from Entity to StateMachine, so I could easily do GetComponent(). But, how do I get that StateMachine back to work then?

I added a variable to my Entity class, with the type "StateMachine". But, in this simple case, I can't fill it with something of the type StateMachine".

To fix that, I thought about something that I once read about: covariance. With covariance, I could fill a StateMachine with a StateMachine, I atleast thought I could.

You can't use covariance on a class, so I created an interface for it, which looks like this:

```
 public interface IStateMachine<out T>
 {
 }
```

And in my Entity class, I have a variable declared:

```
 public IStateMachine<Entity> StateMachine;
```

But, now I need IStateMachine to do his work as an interface, and force the class StateMachine to have a SwitchState method, this is my current situation.

I'm trying to give my IStateMachine the method:

```
 void SwitchState(State<T> state);
```

But then I get the error:

```
 IStateMachine.cs(4,18): error CS1961: The covariant type parameter `T' must be invariantly valid on `IStateMachine<T>.SwitchState(State<T>)'
```

And this is where I get lost. Any help would be appreciated, from solving the error to a way different solution.

Comment: Please use the [unity3d] tag for the Unity game engine. [unity] refers to other Microsoft technology.

Comment: am not game developer so forgive me if my comment sounds stupid, but honestly you should give some more code since I am not able to replicate your situation, also I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142747/why-am-i-getting-the-type-parameter-must-be-invariantly-valid-error) question is very similar to yours

Comment: have you already solved your problem?

Comment: The case isn't there anymore. Yet, I didn't solve the problem yet.